# find data from all field in single table mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Hello I am new at mongodb , I have made server side pagination , working perfect, I have one search textbox in which I type anithing like email , name , number etc it should give me result but I am facting issue in serverside searching data from all field of single table , can anyone give me idea how can I do that

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am not looking for this , I have single search text box in which I type anything like name, email ,number etc , it should give me result

Comment: Then you are talking about using multiple fields with [Text Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) or even using [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/). Either way, all of these questions have been already answered. You are supposed to search for them before posting a question here.